# Angularjs filter out

Tags: angularjs

I have "item.adjustment". The value of adjustment either can be a positive number or a negative number. Based on the sign of the value, I have to display 'adjustments' in two different columns: Positive, and Negative columns.

below is a sample code for my scenario. Can any one help?

```
    <tr>
       <td>Positive</td>
       <td>Negative</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>{{item.adjustment}}</td>
       <td>{{item.adjustment}}</td>
     </tr>
```

Can I do something like this?

```
      <td ng-if="item.adjustment >= 0"/>
      <td ng-if="item.adjustment < 0"/>
```

or any better ways?

Comment: Can you please share expected result table structure?

Answer (score 1):

`ng-if` will show/hide the element based on the condition if that is what you want. But if you want to show different style based on positive or negative value then its better to use `ng-class`.

E.g

```
<td ng-class="{ positive: item.adjustment >= 0 }/>
<td ng-class="{ negative: item.adjustment < 0 }/>
```

Then define these classes

```
.positive {
   color: green;
}

.negative {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot. I play with colors for positive and negative. awesome

Comment: I don't think this answers his question, he wants the text to be placed either in the left `td` or the right based on the positive or negative of the number

Comment: I answered the OP's questions and along with that I also provided a suggestion which is upto OP to accept or not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to do :

your JS

```
    $scope.items = [{adjustment:1}, 
                {adjustment:0.3}, 
                {adjustment:-7},
                {adjustment:0},
                {adjustment:13},
                {adjustment:-4},
                {adjustment:-0.5}];
```

your HTML

```
<tr>
   <td>Positive</td>
   <td>Negative</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
   <td>{{item.adjustment >= 0 ? item.adjustment : ''}}</td>
   <td>{{item.adjustment < 0 ? item.adjustment : ''}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You're welcome ;) May I ask you to tag the question as answered if it fits your needs ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to display them in seperate columns, but still render both `<td>`s. What you can do is wrap them in a span, because setting the `ng-if` on the `<td>` itself won't render the `<td>`, which causes the negative adjustments to be also in the first column.

```
<tr>
   <td>Positive</td>
   <td>Negative</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
   <td><span ng-if="item.adjustment >= 0">{{item.adjustment}}</span></td>
   <td><span ng-if="item.adjustment < 0">{{item.adjustment}}</span></td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want to show/hide the text inside td element conditionally, you should add a span inside the td and use ng-if on that. With your approach, only one of the tds will be displayed for any given item in a table row.

```
  <td><span ng-if="item.adjustment >= 0">item.adjustment</span></td>
  <td><span ng-if="item.adjustment < 0">item.adjustment</span></td>
```

See the plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wLBx9t16BAidFQ7RtiWy?p=preview) which highlights the problem with your approach